# Django in one serialize pull out child objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm, django-serializer

This my models

```
class Dictionary(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    parentId = models.UUIDField(editable=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_end = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, null=True)


class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    status = models.OneToOneField(Dictionary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

this is my urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('get', views.GetViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
    ]
```

This is ViewSet

```
class GetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    MyApiObj = null

    @property
    def api_object(self):
        return namedtuple("ApiObject", self.request.data.keys())(*self.request.data.values())

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        GeneralSerializer.Meta.model = apps.get_model(app_label=self.MyApiObj.app,  model_name=self.MyApiObj.object)
        return GeneralSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        self.MyApiObj = self.api_object
        return self.select_api()

    def select_api(self):
        queryset = QueryHelper.select(self.MyApiObj)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Serializer

```
class GeneralSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = None
        fields = '__all__'
```

My post parameters to django

```
{  
   "app":"leads",
   "object":"Teacher",
   "settings":{ 
   },
   "data":{  

   }
}
```

answer:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John",
        "message": "Hi everyone",
        "status": "e3b86ed4-8794-413b-994c-b1ec0a43eebe"
    }
]
```

Problem is Dictionary(status) model give me id(uuid) but i need whole object  without creating new serializer for Dictionary. i do univeral serializer for all models in my app

Try this:

```
class DictionarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dictionary
        fields = '__all__'


class GeneralSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = DictionarySerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = None
        fields = '__all__'
```

But it is not good for me because 1) Without other serializer 2) I need Universal serializer for all models and with child model in all models of my project. Help me please)

I need something like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "status": {
            "id": "e3b86ed4-8794-413b-994c-b1ec0a43eebe",
            "parentId": "dc6cf7da-b82c-11e9-a2a3-2a2ae2dbcce4",
            "name": "Spravochnik1",
            "date_create": "2019-08-06T09:30:49.355439Z",
            "date_end": "2019-08-06T09:29:57Z"
        },
        "name": "John",
        "message": "Hi everyone"
    }
]
```

Comment: add depth = 1 in meta GeneralSerializer

Comment: Wow thank you very much)))) Sorry i am new in pythan and django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for nested serialization check full ref [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization)
 and for your case add `depth = 1`

```
class GeneralSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    status = DictionarySerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = None
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```